# Can a wake-on-lan packet be sent from WiFi?

Tags: windows, wake-on-lan, magic-packet

I know that you can't wake a computer up with wake on lan if it's connected via WiFi, but will sending the magic packet to wake up a computer that's wired from a computer that's on WiFi work?

Comment: Great question. I guess maybe you have to make sure the card is connected to the wifi before the computer is turned off!   Unless there is some internal software on the WiFi adaptor that makes the connection.

Comment: "From" wifi shouldn't be a problem at all.  "To" a computer on wifi that's asleep can even be done, but it takes a special wifi adapter that will listen in low power mode.

Comment: I had a similar (but more detailed) question about wake-on-lan and found this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1659028/74576

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming that the Wi-Fi and wired networks are on the same broadcast domain. The WoL "magic packet" is really a layer-2 broadcast frame, not a layer-3 packet. As a broadcast, it will be stopped at a layer-3 boundary.