# How can I send a WOL Magic Packet from Win 10 on wifi to wake an Ubuntu computer connected via ethernet cable to the wifi router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wake-on-lan

Novice here.

I have an Arris BGW210-700 wifi router (which is required for AT&T fiber).

Plugged into that via ethernet is an Ubuntu computer that is often sleeping. It's the only device plugged in via ethernet cable. All other devices use wifi.

I've spent hours trying to figure out how to send a Magic Packet from one of my other devices (e.g. Windows 10 computer, or Ubuntu in WSL on Win 10, or Android).

Calling this seems to have no effect:

```
wakeonlan 00:26:9e:89:c9:e5
Sending magic packet to 255.255.255.255:9 with 00:26:9e:89:c9:e5
```

I figured that the only hardwire requirement was that the *sleeping* computer needed to have an ethernet cable between it and the router (which mine does).

But it finally occurred to me: maybe wake-on-LAN only would only work if my sending computer were *also* hardwired to the router. Is that true?

**How can I achieve my goal of waking a computer that is attached to the router, given that no other devices are physically attached to the router (and instead are only connected via wifi)? Thanks!**

<sub>This question was originally at https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74388/how-can-i-send-a-wol-magic-packet-from-win-10-on-wifi-to-wake-an-ubuntu-computer?noredirect=1#comment133430_74388 but then I was told to ask it here instead.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I found a tool that worked: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/easy-wol-wake-on-lan/9nblggh5q03z?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Running that on Win 10, I then provided the MAC Address of the sleeping Ubuntu computer and also:

> Broadcast: No
>
> IP or DNS Address: 192.168.1.255
>
> Port: 9

I'm not sure how I was supposed to know what to provide for the IP field. I saw on my router's config page `Device IPv4 Address     192.168.1.254`, so that's the one I tried first, but it didn't work. Then I tried `192.168.1.255`, and it worked!

Comment: Using a non-existing IP address doesn't work because there's an ARP attempt for that address that will fail. Broadcast - *limited* to 255.255.255.255 or *directed* to 192.168.1.255 - works as long as the destination is in the same L2 segment and listening for a WoL packet. The tool and method you use don't really matter.